# Can an integrated HDMI port work both ways?

Tags: laptop, video, hdmi, graphics

Say I had a laptop [Correction: *notebook*, don't want my thighs medium rare], any OS, and it has an HDMI port built into the side. Would it be remotely possible to hack it into an input, provided it wasn't already designed for that? I would figure all video ports operate straight off the graphics chip, however, are there ways to override that functionality on the driver level? Driver hacks already exist for plenty of things such as the classic example: Bluetooth adapters (so we can play with our PS3 controllers and save a buck) However, is HDMI one of these tamperable interfaces? As far as the interface standard is concerned, **are HDMI ports designed to be either way or are they Input/Output specific?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They cannot.
The ports are only HDMI out.
I you want HDMI in, you'll have to buy HDMI capture card for laptop.

Comment: Video capture is totally different hardware-wise from video generation. They're as different as speaking and listening.