# Using Surface Pro as a recording PC

Tags: tablet, video-capture

I want to know if it would be possible to connect my laptop to my tablet with a mini display port to HDMI cable and use the tablet to capture the video stream from the laptop i.e. record the screen. Anything else I would need besides a cable (hopefully no capture card bs)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can an integrated HDMI port work both ways?](http://superuser.com/questions/442470/can-an-integrated-hdmi-port-work-both-ways), [Using video ports 'backwards'](http://superuser.com/questions/510358/using-video-ports-backwards)

Comment: You could use some remote support software that supports session recording - records everything on the remote screen and keep it as a video. (One that I use is TeamViewer)

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't use the ports like that.

The Mini DP is used for display OUT, and cannot be used inversely to take HDMI input. You'd be better off getting a program like [Fraps](http://www.fraps.com/) or [CamStudio](http://camstudio.org/) on your laptop to record your screen.

Hope this helps!

Comment: The problem with that is that my performance will suffer. Is there a way maybe using USB 3.0?

Comment: Not that I know of. You could take the complicated route of using an external recorder, eg [something like this](http://www.vgacapture.com/). Fraps is known for crushing performance, but there are workarounds such as recording to another hard drive, optimizing your laptop, etc.